# Can the instantaneous center of rotation of a vertebrae be mathematically determined for flexion of lumbar?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy, movement, vertebra, spine

I am starting to learn spinal anatomy and I want to determine the Instantaneous axes of rotation (IAR) of individual vertebrae. I have referred many research papers but haven't come across any useful material.
Let's say I have the center points of superior and inferior plates of L5. Similarly I have the center point of superior plate of S1.
Is there any way to mathematically determine the IAR for L5 for lumbar flexion(say) ?.